# PUT method gives NULL JSON

Tags: java, spring, postman

```
@PutMapping(path = "{studentId}")
public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String email){

    studentService.updateStudent(studentId, name, email);
}

@Transactional
public void updateStudent(Long studentId, String name, String email){

    Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Student with " +studentId+" does not exist" ));


        student.setName(name);
        student.setEmail(email);
}
```

}

The problem is when I do PUT method in POSTMAN it gives no error but values in "name" and "email" are NULL. How can I fix it?
Here is my POSTMAN request.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHYVW.png

Comment: Your api expects optional request params and you are giving request body in postman

Answer (score 1):

Your api expects optional request params and you are giving request body in postman. The above api will work for `/student/1?name=John&email=example@abc.com`
If you want to use request body to work with this api i.e., form data submit them change the api to use request body which will be (@RequestBody Student studentData) where Student is a class having 2 string variables name & email. You can create a new class StudentRequest having only request attributes for your put/post apis or you can reuse Student class.

```
@PutMapping(path = "{studentId}")
public void updateStudent(
    @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
    @RequestBody(required = true) Student student){

    studentService.updateStudent(studentId, student);
}


@Transactional
public void updateStudent(Long studentId, Student studentData){
  
     Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Student with " +studentId+" does not exist" ));
 
     student.setName(studentData.getName());
     student.setEmail(studentData.getEmail());
     studentRepository.save(student);
}
```

Comment: as far as i see there must be this line at the end to preset student object after changing `studentRepository.save(student);`

Comment: Yeah but the issue was with the api request. But I'll add the save part anyway.